# Converting String to Date format in MS Access

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, ms-access-2013

I have field which show the month and year in a string format. How can I convert it into MMYYYY format in Microsoft Access?

The field values are as follows:

```
Period Code
M01-15
M02-15
M03-15
M04-15
M05-15
```

The above values are sent by the client.

I want to get the values in any date format preferably in MMYYYY.

The result should be as:

```
Period Code
012015
022015
032015
042015
052015
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateSerial and Format:

```
MDate = "M03-15"
MonthYear = Format(DateSerial(Mid(MDate, 5), Mid(MDate, 2, 2), 1), "mmyyyy")
' Returns: 032015
```

Or brute force with Replace:

```
MDate = "M04-15"
MonthYear = Replace(Mid(MDate, 2), "-", "20")
' Returns: 042015
```